# Defined VBA protection for new sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I use some kind of check list with few Worksheets. Each Worksheet has protection with other restrictions. All have that same main code, only restrictions are others.

I use that VBA code to protect each sheet of my excel individually, each code is with new start executed. It allows to use empty cells, but all others cells with text stay protected.
It works perfectly, but it need to be programmed for each sheet.

My problem is that, if someone decides, that he need one more sheet. It won't be protected at all...

Have someone any Idea, how to make one Makro that protect all **new sheets** without overwriting restrictions on others and naturally without my participation in it each time?

It should work in similar way too, all empty cells = not protected, all with text = protected

```
Public Sub Mes2()
  Dim strPassword As String
  strPassword = "Athens"
  With Sheets("Pool Processing")

    .Unprotect Password:=strPassword
    .Cells.Locked = True

    On Error Resume Next
    .Range("A:AA").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Locked = False
    On Error GoTo 0
    .Protect Password:=strPassword, UserInterfaceOnly:=True, AllowFormattingCells:=True, AllowFormattingRows:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: 1) Will all sheets be protected? 2) Will they all have the same protection? 3) Will they all use the same password?

Comment: Use the `Workbook_NewSheet` procedure

Comment: ^^Getting to that @Fratyx :-) Yes though would help to know the answers to the other questions. I was gonna to suggest the same thing https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-newsheet-event-excel

Comment: 1) yes, 2) all new, yes 3) yes.  My code need to be always at start executed.  l How do i make that with that procedure? I can only make other code that protect all cells that will be in real time filled out. 
     Example: "Call Tabelle1.auto_Mes2"